# is bitset data stored in reverse order?

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset, std-bitset

I was trying out [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and after getting wrong results for a while I noticed that the results were in reverse order. Tried searching on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) page but couldn't find any source on this and hence need an confirmation. This should be default behaviour across different compilers too?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bitset<7> bin('C');
    cout << bin << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i){ cout << bin[i]; }
    return 0;
}
```

> `1000011`
>
> `1100001`

Comment: try this.
[Stackoverflow: Why are the bits of a std::bitset in reverse order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4975037/3764546)

Comment: Actually, this is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483123/why-does-stdbitset-expose-bits-in-little-endian-fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++ standard:

> When converting between an object
>   of class `bitset<N>` and a value of some integral type, bit position pos corresponds to the bit value 1 << pos.
>   The integral value corresponding to two or more bits is the sum of their bit values.